# Emacs code completion for .org files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using emacs and have code completion working. This works nicely
on source code files `.f`, `.c`, ... However it does not complete for
`.org` files. Is there a command I can put in my `.emacs` file to solve the problem?

Comment: What sort of information would you want to complete in Org files? Most Org syntax is quite compact already.

Comment: When I am writing my notes, it would be good to be able to complete words while typing just as I do when writing code. I usually might forget the exact name of a routine, and it would be helpful to get the drop down menu for me to select the appropriate one.

Comment: You want to complete source code, e.g. class or function names, defined in other files, while working in Org?

Comment: Yes, if I happen to have them open. Will also help with grammer too if a word was used before.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding words that already exist in the file is easy. Use [`dabbrev-expand`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html), bound to `M-/` by default:

> Expand previous word "dynamically".
>
> Expands to the most recent, preceding word for which this is a prefix. If no suitable preceding word is found, words following point are considered.  If still no suitable word is found, then look in the buffers accepted by the function pointed out by variable  `` `dabbrev-friend-buffer-function' ``.

If you want to see all options, use `dabbrev-completion` (`C-M-/`) instead:

> Completion on current word. Like `M-/` but finds all expansions in the current buffer and presents suggestions for completion.

Expanding code defined in other buffers will be trickier, and I don't have a good solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

This has solved the problem

```
(define-globalized-minor-mode real-global-auto-complete-mode
   auto-complete-mode (lambda ()
     (if (not (minibufferp (current-buffer)))
        (auto-complete-mode 1))
     ))
(real-global-auto-complete-mode t)
```